# warning (pdf backend): pop empty color page stack 0

Tags: pdftex, color, luatex, tcolorbox, warnings

I've been receiving this warning and for the past several hours (erh, something like 12 hours now).  I've been trying to narrow down what's been causing it, but to no avail.  I managed to cut down the project to ~1000 lines of code and still produce the warning, but I've tried cutting out tens of different things from that ~1000 lines, and so far, whatever I try to cut beyond that makes the warning go away, making it incredibly difficult to debug.  There's also of course no line the warning points to and no visual indication in the document that something is wrong to point me in the right direction.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6xfgYpCM4U3MmxpcEVUc1ZBV0k) is a link to the actual project that produces the warning.  So far I've managed to deduce that `\includeonly{basics,apd}` reproduces the error, but if you remove either `basics` or `apd` here, the warning goes away.  Furthermore, while I haven't tested ever two-chapter combination, it is the only two-chapter combination I have found that will reproduce the warning (and no chapter by itself will reproduce it).

I am also able to remove ~half the lines from either of these files to still retain the warning, but, besides the actual amount of code I'm removing, I don't see any pattern in the code that does and does not reproduce the warning.  I've also been able to remove the title page, table of contents, references, and index, and still retain the warning.

I apologize for not being able to give any sort of MWE, but I really wasn't able to get it down much more than `\includeonly{basics,apd}` even after hours and hours of experimenting.  Hopefully at least someone has an idea as to what this error even *means* so that I have a better chance of debugging it?

(FWIW, the pdf backend I've been using is LuaLaTeX, though I've confirmed that pdfLaTeX produces the warning just the same (from the TeX Live 2016 distro).  Perhaps it's also worth noting that Texmaker (my current IDE) does *not* report this warning and I have to go into the log file to find it.)

Comment: I fear this question will be closed, but please, could you upload a .zip-file of the project? Couldn't find a way to download the whole project, without adding it to my Google-account first.

Comment: No chance you might post a MWE nonetheless?  I sense there is a legitimate question, and think that you might get a better response if you post one.

Comment: @RunarTrollet I've updated the link in the question to now point to a .zip instead.

Comment: @AFeldman Unforutnately I cannot.  "Body is limited to 30000.  You entered 70000+."  And that was just one of the two files . . .

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean.

Comment: where did you get your code for the titlepage? seems like it has the exact same problem as the newly started question [adding border to table of contents in xepersian package](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/316687/adding-border-to-table-of-contents-in-xepersian-package)

Comment: Also, I get lots of warnings with your project because of how you define your environments, try removing/changing `label separator=`

Comment: The title page, as well as much of the formatting, comes from the Legrand Orange Book template (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/the-legrand-orange-book).

Comment: @RunarTrollet What warnings are you getting?  `label separator` is only in a relatively new version of `tcolorbox`.  When I was using ShareLaTeX, which evidently didn't have the latest versions, I had to manually install the latest version into my project directory in order to make use of this feature, and certainly before doing so it would complain about an unrecognized key or something of the like.

I decided to delete the `label separator` lines just in case, and unfortunately this did not resolve the warning =/

Comment: looks like tcolorbox, I added a fix to my answer

Comment: before you edit your project you might want to save (or at least don't delete;-) that zip file with the bad version, should you want to report a bug to tcolorbox having an example (even if it's big) is helpful...

Comment: unrelated but all those numeric labels like `\label{sct4.4}` seem like a bad idea:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What makes you say that about the labels?  Perhaps for a section it was a bad idea, because the section has a name, but there are hundreds of references that don't have names and coming up with an easy-to-remember label for all of them was (I thought) more difficult than just using the numbers.

Also, the .zip should remain there for a pretty long time, if not forever =)

Comment: using numeric labels is just a really bad idea and pretty much negates the original purpose of having labels at all. the whole point is that you can edit the document, adding new sections and all cross referencing adjusts and works.  so when you have edited the document and you have section 5.6 and it has internal label `sct4.4` latex itself will be fine but any human looking at the source will be massively confused.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well what it means is that's you've corrupted the colour stack. Unlike font changes colour is not an intrinsic attribute of a tex box, so colour changes are managed by nodes marking the change of state *whatsit*, Originally it was very hard to maintain colour correctly over page breaks, as the macro package needed to normalise colour in the page headings and could not reset the current colour for the text at the start of a page as the page breaking routine can not easily insert a special there.

dvips introduced the notion of a colour stack where the driver maintains a stack of colours that are handled correctly at a page break, and the macro layer just needs to push and pop colours on to this stack rather than trying to set the "correct" colour at points over which it has little control.

pdftex (and luatex) extend this model further and have specific push/pop commands

more or less:

```
 \pdfcolorstack  push {red}
...
 \pdfcolorstack pop
```

so you get the error if you have a `\colorstack pop` without a matching push, or in latex macro wrappers, if you have a `\reset@color` without a `\set@color`

---

I guess this fixes it, modify  `\tcbtitle` after loading tcolorbox in your structure file:

```
\usepackage{tcolorbox} % Required for creating the theorem, definition, exercise and corollary boxes.

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tcbtitle{\ifx\tcbtitletext\@empty\else%
  {\leavevmode\color{tcbcol@title}\kvtcb@fonttitle
 \kvtcb@haligntitle\kvtcb@before@title
  \tcbtitletext\kvtcb@after@title}\fi}
\makeatother
```

or perhaps better

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tcbtitle{\ifx\tcbtitletext\@empty\else%
  {\kvtcb@fonttitle\kvtcb@haligntitle\kvtcb@before@title
\leavevmode\color{tcbcol@title}\tcbtitletext\kvtcb@after@title}\fi}
\makeatother
```

so you delay the color until after `\kvtcb@before@title`

Comment: I can confirm that this does indeed fix the warning.  It is just a tiny bug in the `tcolorbox` package then?  How on earth did you figure that out anyways?  TeXnician?  More like TeXNinja!

Comment: @JonathanGleason I've used TeX before:-)

Comment: the warning is shown on a page that has a tcbox coloured environment at the top of the page, which was the main hint, plus a history of various packages dropping specials  when doing page breaks or vsplits as (depending how you look) a zero sized box just containing a colour whatsit can look empty, so I suspected the package was dropping a  whatsit at a page break leaving matching restore. so in your code and tcolorbox replaced every \color by \leavevmode\color (not in general a good idea) but the warning went so it was just a matter of finding which one.

Comment: I will add a `\leavevmode` to `\tcbtitle` as you have suggested. Hopefully, there is no user code with `\tcbtitle` where leaving the vertical mode introduces problems. :-)

Comment: @ThomasF.Sturm as we both know, you can never win all the time here, just a matter of avoiding being tripped up as often as possible:-)

Answer (score 9):

The warning "pop empty color stack" is usually caused by color stack commands out of order. A typical scenario is the use of low level box set command `\setbox` instead of LaTeX box set macros (`\sbox`, environment `lrbox`, ...).
When LaTeX sets a color, then the color reset command is issued after the current group. Therefore LaTeX box macros add a group layer around the contents of the box. Without this additional group, the color reset (pop operation of the color stack) leaks out of the box and is executed at the wrong time:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{document}
\setbox0=\hbox{\color{red}Red}
\null
\end{document}
```

At the begin of the box the color red is put on the stack. Then the box is closed and the pop operation leaks out of the box and is executed at the time of the box definition, before the box is used. Push and pop are out of order (in the example the box is not used, only the pop special).

Solution: A group keeps the pop special inside:

```
\setbox0{\begingroup\color{red}Red\endgroup}
```

because it is inserted after `\endgroup` before the box closes.
LaTeX's `\sbox` does this automatically:

```
\sbox0{\color{red}Red}
```

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, I added a `\begingroup` `\endgroup` pair after every appearance of the command `\color` in my document, and the warning still appeared.   Must it then be a package that's causing this somehow behind the scenes?

Comment: @JonathanGleason Yes, this can be in a package. The low level `\setbox` is seldom used in user code. Packages or classes are more likely.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek tcolorbox: (it's not our fault:-)